# Selecting a Row to be copied in datagridview with a checkbox

Tags: sql, vb.net, button, datagridview, sql-update

I am currently working in VB.net, windows form applications. I have a datagridview that I want to use a button to update certain rows that are checked in a check box. However, I am having a hard time selecting the check box cell. This is a data-bound source as well, it is running with an sql client.

```
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim row As DataGridViewRow
    Dim cell As DataGridViewCell
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    With DataGridLine2
        For Each row In .Rows
            For Each DataGridViewCheckBoxCell In .Rows
                If DataGridViewCheckBoxCell.checkstate = 1 Then
                    Using conn1 As New SqlConnection(connstring)
                        conn1.Open()
                        Using comm1 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("UPDATE Production.dbo.tblFCordered SET Ordered = true", conn1)
                        End Using
                    End Using
                ElseIf DataGridViewCheckBoxCell.checkstate = 0 Then
                    Exit Sub
                End If

            Next

        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you update your question with error message? When yo refer to row (container of the checkbox) it seems that you are not referring to checkbox inside of it since it's a different element... error message would be helpful to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: System member missing error message